# ¿Cómo validar un textarea de bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Estoy usando Bootstrap, ya estoy importando las librerias de bootstrapValidator.min.css & bootstrapValidator.min.js. Mi problema es que no se valida el textarea, este es mi código:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" role="form" 
                      enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="validaEnvioCorreo" name="validaEnvioCorreo">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="box box-armando">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Escribe tu mensaje</h3>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="remitente">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Asunto:" name="asunto" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea type="text-area" id="compose-textarea" class="form-control" 
                                              style="height: 300px" name="cuerpo">
                                    </textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> Adjuntar archivo
                                        <input name="archivoAdj" type="file" />
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="help-block">Max. 32MB</p>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- /.box-body -->

                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Borrador</button> -->
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviarAdj"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> &nbsp;Enviar</button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Descartar</button> -->
                            </div> <!-- /.box-footer -->
                        </div> <!-- /. box -->
                    </div> <!-- /.col-md-9 -->
 </form>
```

Y el código javascript es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#validaEnvioCorreo').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        asunto: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'El asunto es requerido y no puede estar vacío'
                }
            }
        },
        cuerpo: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'El correo electronico es requerido y no puede estar vacío'
                }
            }
        }
    } //termina fields
});
     });
</script>
```

Mi código solo llega a validar el input, pero el textarea no.
¿Cómo valido el textarea?

Comment: Tiene que haber otro problema... porque [aquí](http://jsbin.com/zipilan/edit?html,js,output) funciona tu código

Comment: Yo tambien tengo ese mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que usas Bootstrap, prueba con hacer lo siguiente: Colocar required al final del campo que quieres validar..

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
        <span>Descripción</span>
        <textarea rows="3" id="texto" name="texto" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion" required></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo le quité el id al text-area, ya que ese id tenía otra función, y que estaba bloqueando a bootstrap.
En sí, el código quedó de esta manera:

```
<div class="form-group">
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="cuerpo" style="height: 300px"></textarea>
</div>
```